# Unexpected update result on the quickly nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, repeat, multiplication, assign

Why couldn't the first element but the whole column be updated below?

```
>>> x=2*[2*[1]]
>>> x
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
>>> x[0][0]=2
>>> x
[[2, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even tho this is a clear duplicate but use `range`:

```
>>> x=[[1 for i in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
>>> x
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
>>> x[0][0]=2
>>> x
[[2, 1], [1, 1]]
>>>
```

At least still able to do:

```
>>> x=[[1]*2 for x in range(2)]
>>> x[0][0]=2
>>> x
[[2, 1], [1, 1]]
>>>
```